# Mailchimp: Deserializing HttpWebResponse data to custom class

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, mailchimp

I am trying to get accustomed to Mailchimps API before jumping into NuGet packages or outside wrappers to see how easy it is to use. Right now, I'm just trying to do a GET on the API Root which should return my account information.

I created my objects to hold the data:

```
class UserAccount
{
    string account_id { get; set; }
    string account_name { get; set; }
    Contact contact { get; set; }
    bool pro_enabled { get; set; }
    string last_login { get; set; }
    int total_subscribers { get; set; }
    List<Links> _links { get; set; }
}

class Contact
{
    string company { get; set; }
    string addr1 { get; set; }
    string addr2 { get; set; }
    string city { get; set; }
    string state { get; set; }
    string zip { get; set; }
    string country { get; set; }
}

class Links
{
    string rel { get; set; }
    string href { get; set; }
    string method { get; set; }
    string targetSchema { get; set; }
}
```

And then I'm trying a simple GET:

```
 try {
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "apikey" + apiKey);
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    UserAccount account = new UserAccount();

                    account = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<UserAccount>(data);
                    var dynObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(data);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
```

Deserializing to my custom class gives me all nulls. Deserializing to the dynamic object gives me everything I expect. My only guess is that it could be the class names but I have no idea what it could be otherwise.

This is an "example response" from Mailchimps API page:

```
{
  "account_id": "8d3a3db4d97663a9074efcc16",
  "account_name": "Freddie's Jokes",
  "contact": {
    "company": "Freddie's Jokes",
    "addr1": "675 Ponce De Leon Ave NE",
    "addr2": "Suite 5000",
    "city": "Atlanta",
    "state": "GA",
    "zip": "30308",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "last_login": "2015-09-15 14:25:37",
  "total_subscribers": 413,
  "_links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Root.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "lists",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Lists/Collection.json",
      "schema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Lists.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "reports",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Reports/Collection.json",
      "schema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Reports.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "conversations",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/conversations",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Conversations/Collection.json",
      "schema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Conversations.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "campaigns",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Collection.json",
      "schema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Campaigns.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "automations",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Automations/Collection.json",
      "schema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Automations.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "templates",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/templates",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Templates/Collection.json",
      "schema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Templates.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "file-manager",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/file-manager",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/FileManager/Namespace.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "authorized-apps",
      "href": "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/authorized-apps",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/AuthorizedApps/Collection.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I made this question too quickly. It turns out that I am simply an idiot, and my class data members were not public. By simply adding public the data is all where it should be.